# Firebase Android Crash Reporting

Tags: firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm using 'Firebase Android Crash Reporting' and can't make scenario when crash happens and we don't need to manually send it.

So I should 'log' or 'report' something manually all the time I think there could be Exception?

Like 'Fabric' works. Is there any chance to achieve that?

Comment: You can also check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOJ2BfZ5lak).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firebase Crash Reporting automatically reports all uncaught exceptions. So if you let exceptions "bubble up", they'll show up in Firebase automatically.

If your code already catches/handles/swallows exceptions, you can [pass those exceptions on to Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android). An example from the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/crash/FirebaseCrash.html#report(java.lang.Throwable)):

```
try {
     // Some code here...
 } catch (Exception e) {
     // Don't know what to do with this...
     FirebaseCrash.log("Caught an unexpected exception while doing some work");
     FirebaseCrash.report(e);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, was some kind of mistake with generated .json file.
Renewed it from console and all works as you said.

Answer (score 1):

FirebaseCrash.log("SQL database failed to initialize");